# Post on Facebook without Share Prompt in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, share

Is there a possibility where I can make a button on which when I click, the contents directly get shared on facebook without showing our user the share prompt dialog box?

I referred it online and found that its possible through mobile devices:
http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-post-message-on-your-facebook-wall-without-using-Facebook-dialog-Box-1419.php

The question is can we make some sort of ajax call and get this done on web apps.

We used Following code

```
<?php
require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');
$config = array(
  'appId' => 'My app ID', /*Your APP ID*/
  'secret' => 'My Secret ID', /*Your APP Secret Key*/
  'allowSignedRequest' => false 
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

  if($user_id) {
    try {
      $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
      error_log($e->getType());
      error_log($e->getMessage());
    }   
  } else {
    // No user, print a link for the user to login
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
  }


  $response = $facebook->api(
  "/me/feed",
  "POST",
   array (
      'message' => 'This is a test message',
      'link' => 'www.google.com'
     /*        'picture' => '{picture}',
      'caption' => '{caption}',
      'description' => '{description}'*/
  )
);
  ?>
```

But its returns : " Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action throw in file"
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that's a kind of security behaviour of facebook.  Don't you think so?

Comment: Yes But if is possible for ipad/iphone dont you think it should be possible for web application. Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can using the Graph API. On the button click you just have to make a `\POST` call to `/me/feed`.

Learn more about publishing a feed via Graph API and what all parameters are available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/#publish).

Permission required: `publish_stream`

Using **PHP SDK:**

```
$response = $facebook->api(
    "/me/feed",
    "POST",
    array (
        'message' => 'This is a test message',
        'link' => '{link}',
        'picture' => '{picture}',
        'caption' => '{caption}',
        'description' => '{description}'
    )
);
```

Direct **HTTP** Request-

```
POST /me/feed
Host: graph.facebook.com

message=This+is+a+test+message
...
```

You can check your calls in [Graph API Explorer](http://graph.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

---

**Edit:**

To ask for the required permissions:

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'publish_stream'
);

$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

You can read more about permissions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/).

Comment: I tried using /me/feed directly on the browser so I think I might have to try making an ajax call or a curl request to this. Thank you very much, would get back to you on this.
FYI: I viewed this url on the browser. https://graph.facebook.com/[myId]/feed

Comment: Any publishing request is a post request. ou cant directly run it i a browser. Instead use Graph API Explorer tool, I've added it in the answer

Comment: The Graph API explorer returns: {
   "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /explorer",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check it and help to solve my problem . Thanks.

Comment: You're not requesting any permission. If you read my answer carefully I've mentioned that user must grant `publish_stream` to able app to post on their behalf. Anyways I'm editing the answer showing how it is done.

Comment: Thanks Sahil Your Answer Helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/
When coding the wep app, you only have to provide the App Id and the App Secret, then you should have to specify the content to be posted.
You should try also the Javascript Facebook SDK, you'll find it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript or you could go further and try the C# SDK, this one is a little bit more complex, but you will be able to do so much more.
Have fun coding!!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply .Let me check it.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Review it and place what kind of share you want.

This is the long process to be handle so. you need to study it.